# Mozilla Firefox crashes on translation of language

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-translate

I'm using google translator API to translate the text of website. But when I change the language to translate the content, browser (Mozilla Firefox) crashes (this happens only in case of Mozilla Firefox). I tried to find out the issue but everything seems okay. Help me to resolve this issue.
The code I used is below:

```
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```